# Flutter remove built in box shadow of Material Stepper

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm using the Stepper from material design in my desktop application with Flutter. But as shown in the image, the Stepper has a default BoxShadow which I want to remove. I already looked through the stepper.dart file which builds the stepper, but I couldn't find any decoration which would result in the shadow.

[image]

This is the extract of my Stepper implementation:

```
child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
  child: Stepper(
    steps: steps,
    type: StepperType.horizontal,
    currentStep: currentStep,
    onStepContinue: next,
    onStepCancel: cancel,
    onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
  ),
),
```

I'm guessing that it is some kind of configuration from material design which automatically assigns a shadow to the stepper.

Is there a way to configure/remove the Shadow of the stepper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go into source code you'll see `Material` widget with `elevation: 2.0`

so, I think you have two choices:

1. create your own Stepper based on source code (with removed elevation property)
2. set shadow color to transparent like this

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
    child: Stepper(
      steps: steps,
      type: StepperType.horizontal,
      currentStep: currentStep,
      onStepContinue: next,
      onStepCancel: cancel,
      onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I have now changed the stepper source code of material design. Would these changes get overwritten when upgrading Flutter?